# populate array in sqlite while

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, sqlite, populate

I am doing something fundamental wrong but I am searching for better examples on the net and is coming up short :-(

in .h
    @interface MyDataViewController : UIViewController {

```
NSArray *array;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array;
```

in m

```
@synthesize array;
```

succesful dbretrieval:

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            //I guess this one is wrong but I cant figure it out.. (tired?)
            array = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

//testoutput to textfield:
            //myName.text  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
//testoutput to nslog:
            NSLog(@"Data: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]);

        }
```

Outputs the last from sqlitequeryn:

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your output and what do you expect from this? You are directly putting a NSString into a NSArray, of which might, or might not be done several times for a static NSArray.

If you are planning on putting several strings into your array, you should have a NSMutableArray and simply addObject every time you loop through your while:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...code....
while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)]];
}
```

Comment: works like a charm.
how do I set this question to answered...? it says "I can accept an anser within 2 min..."

Comment: great! don't forget to handle error messages in your sqlite3 queries, if you absolutely have to use it. I would rather recommend [Core Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Data) for basically any db-application for iPhone. A nice tutorial is [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) by Ray Wenderlich, who also has a lot of other useful tutorials :)

Comment: thx, I will remember to handle the error messages. As of now I will use a static db with controlled querys so I hope that wont be a hazzle.